# rotate x axis labels in ios-charts

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I know label rotation is not supported in ios-charts. Any issue asking for this is promptly closed however this is a very *basic* feature. I've seen people posts about how to do it in MPAndroidChart (which this is based on) but those solutions appear to be Android specific. Does anyone know of a way to get 45 or 90 degree labels rotations for a bar chart in iOS-charts?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289898/drawing-rotated-text-with-nsstring-drawinrect and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089756/rotating-nsstring-in-swift

Comment: thanks, while good for rotating text in general, it doesn't really help in this specific framework, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: They share the same strategy, why won't it work? All using CG

Comment: the problem is I don't see individual labels exposed via the API, maybe if I start hacking the framework then yes I could use standard methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - let me emphasize that you are very wrong:

1. MPAndroidChart existed for a long time without any issue about rotating x-axis labels, so there wasn't a need for anyone.
2. In ios-Charts there was **one** issue about it, tagged as a feature request, and pending until yesterday (Oct 11). There was one other opened recently, marked as duplicate issue.

Secondly:
I've implemented this feature in the latest `master`. Please pull from `master` until there's a version release.

Comment: awesome. I assume cocoapods will pick that up too?

Comment: Yes, the moment we make a release version :-)

Comment: I'm probably blind but I don't see it. Is it in ChartXAxis?

Comment: I see the method in ChartXAxis master but not in the 2.1.5 tag

Comment: As I've said: "Please pull from master until there's a version release."

Comment: Hello. Is there any possibility to make the label multiline? I really need to show really long texts as the description of the xAxis of the HorizontalBarChart and even worse is the fact that I need it to be located to the left from the chart itself. Adding a long text just shifts and compresses the chart

Comment: Use "\n", or set `wordWrapEnabled` to true

Comment: Hi guys use it barChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle       = -90

Answer (score 8):

To rotate a label you need to do the following:

```
someChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = CGFloat(rotationAngle) // -90.0 or -45.0
```

Examples:

```
barChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -45.0 
lineChartView.xAxis.labelRotationAngle = -90.0
```