# How to rotate String and saved this String as UIImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgaffinetransform, uigraphicscontext

I need to rotate the `String` and save this rotating string as `UIImage`.

Let say my given String is = **HELLO WORLD**

Now i need to first rotate(say 45 degree) it and than saved as `UIImage` so i can show this `UIImage` into my `UIImageView`

Please help me . So i can  rotate the `String` and save this rotating string as `UIImage` in Swift?.

I found this answer [Drawing rotated text with NSString drawInRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289898/drawing-rotated-text-with-nsstring-drawinrect). But not able to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the below code helps u,I achieved the same result of rotating the string in 45 degree

```
-(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text
         atPoint:(CGPoint)   point
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(65, 65),NO,0.0);

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 50, 30);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(32.5, 32.5));
CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 4));
CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-32.5, -32.5));
//[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font ];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
[paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:12],
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],

                              NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};

[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withAttributes:attributes];


UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
}
```

Below is screenshot where i achieved the result[image]

Comment: can u help me to find out the height and  width of string as my string content is dynamic

Comment: you can check in stackoverflow.like the above link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324379/how-to-calculate-the-width-of-a-text-string-of-a-specific-font-and-font-size